# Driver's License Points for non-local licenses

Tags: international-travel, driving-licenses

Many jurisdictions around the world have a points based system for measuring driving offences. In some places, like Italy, a new license holder starts off with a fixed number of points which are then deducted based on the severity of the offence committed. When a certain threshold is reached, the licence is then revoked or suspended for a fixed period of time. In other cases, like New York State, a new license holder starts with no points, and points are added after an offence based on its severity. Just like above, after a certain threshold of points is reached, the license is revoked or suspended. In each case, a driver's data is added to a system where it can be accessed by any law enforcement officer.

For example, if I'm caught for speeding today in New York City and receive 3 points on my license, a police officer will add that information to a central database. If, tomorrow, I'm caught for speeding again, a totally different officer will be able to access information about my license and determine that I'm a repeat offender.

In most of these places, you are also legally allowed to drive with a foreign driver's license, with or without an international driving permit. These foreign licenses may not confirm to the same format as the locally issued licenses for that jurisdiction. For instance, some Indian states still issue paper licenses without any digital chip or machine readable data. This license will not be readable by a points system for New York State. **How do such jurisdictions keep a track of driving offences for visitors or tourists who do not have a local license?**

Comment: Maybe your last line should have an addition of 'Or don't they?'

Comment: It sounds like as long as you speed in New York the same amount that you speed in Italy, you should be fine.

Comment: Just do not speed at all, nor do anything else that would put points on/take point off your license.

Comment: Anecdotal and not really answer worth but a couple of times in the US I have been pulled over speeding and nicely waved my Australian license and rental car agreement at the officer and been let off with a verbal warning.  Another time I was given a ticket and had to see a judge who was a dead ringer for Boss Hog from the Dukes of Hazard. I went in thinking I could talk my way out of it but when I saw him I was like "yes sir, no sir, here's my money sir"

Comment: @PeterM Oh no, that's really sad. Is there a significant difference in how court fines are administered in the US and Australia?

Comment: @crayarikar In Australia you get a fine for the speeding and you pay it (assuming that you did not just lose your license for your indiscretion).  In the US the speeding fine is just one component of the bottom line that you end up paying.  They tack on all sorts of "fees" and "taxes" that increase the total by a significant amount.

Comment: @crayarikar And then there is the "$ per mph over the limit" they charge which is based on the posted limit and not the enforced limit - EG I can do 10 mph over on the interstates in the US and the cops won't even get out of bed to pull me over. But at 10+ mph  over the limit and not only do they pull you over but your fine is assessed as 10+ mph over the limit and not difference between what they enforce and what speed you are doing.

Comment: @PeterM Suppose the police only bothered to chase thieves who steal more than $10. By your argument, when a thief is caught after stealing $15, he should only have to return $5...

Comment: @DavidRicherby And that is the issue.  One one hand the police have said that stealing less than $10 in effect is not a crime and I can go on stealing $10 all day long to my hearts content. On the other hand steal $15 just once and you get charged with stealing $15.

Comment: @PeterM Do something a bit bad and it's not worth dealing with; do something really bad and you get charged with... doing the actual thing you actually did. I'm really not seeing the problem with this.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The problem is that it now becomes subjective as to what "bad" is.  I do 10 mph over the limit and a particular cop chooses to enforce or not enforce the law depending on how he *feels* about it.  You don't see an issue with cops choosing to enforce laws based on their feelings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Border states such as New York have reciprocity data sharing agreements with neighboring provinces (Ontario and Quebec in the case of NY State).

A Canadian, say with an Ontario licence caught speeding in NY can have Ontario demerit points assessed against their Ontario licence. If they have too many points (including whatever points they may have earned at home) (oversimplifying a bit) their Ontario licence will no longer be valid, which means it's not legal for them to drive in Ontario or in NY State. Their insurance will probably increase in cost before that. Presumably the same is true in reverse of the NY State driver in Ontario or Quebec who misinterprets the 100km/h limit as 100mph and gets herself stopped.

This would indicate to me that they don't keep track *themselves* of points on foreign licenses.

Of course that's only NY State. Each state (and DC, I assume) can do things their own way. I try to avoid such interactions with the local authorities, even in places like the US where most of the police are honest.